# Definition of the Derivative of a Sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives

I am having a bit of trouble using the definition of the derivative to find the $b_n$. Here is the problem, and a bit of my attempt.

> Suppose $\{b_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence and $f$ is differentiable at $a$. Use the definition of the derivative to determine $b_n$ such that $\{b_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ has a limit $f'(a)$ as $n \to \infty$. The final answer will depend on $f, a$ and $n$.

So I know that the definition of the derivative, in general is $\displaystyle g'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{g(x + h) - g(x)}{h}$, and I know that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = f'(a)$.

If $f(n) = b_n$, then we want to show that the sequence tends to $f'(a)$ as $n$ gets larger.

I am not sure how to proceed from here...Would appreciate some help and advice for this question.

Comment: Hint: let $b_n = f(a+\frac1n)-f(a)/(1/n)$

Comment: @Hyperion can you explain how $1/n$ was found? Is it because we can use $1/n$ in place of $h$, but instead, as $n \to \infty$, $1/n \to 0$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct in your thinking there